# inhomogenous Fredholm equation

Tags: real-analysis, nonlinear-analysis

I am new to non-linear integral equations and want to know how to solve non-linear Fredholm integral equations of the following form generally:

$u(x)=c+\lambda\int_{0}^{1}u^n(y)dy$ where $c,\lambda\in \mathbb{R}$ and $n\in \mathbb{N}$ with $n\geq 1$.

I know that typically these are solved via a substitution method using the Resolvent Kernel function. The representation formula for the solution is given as follows:
$u(x)=1+\lambda\int_{0}^{1}R(x,t;\lambda)u^n(y)dy$, and the resolvent Kernel is given by:

$R(x,t;\lambda)=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\lambda^{m-1}K_m(x,t)$

Are the $K_m$ kernels always $1$, and how do we go from here. The non-linear term of $u^n(y)$ is throwing me off.

**EXTRA**

As an aside/bonus, I am assuming the solution $u$ will be an $L^2$ function, but I also want to know what happens if we consider Sobolev spaces like $H^2$ and other function spaces, if the solution methodology changes.

Comment: I am not familiar with the topic, but quick googling has found this paper, which considers slightly more general case, but very close to yours. www.mdpi.com/1999-4893/10/3/89/pdf

Comment: And another paper which offers a Newton-type method for numerically solving such equations https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.07446.pdf